# ContentFlow (coverflow) - Need to make it work + Tabs and panes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs, coverflow

Im using this plugin:

http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

Here is my test site:

http://flexbeltsite.info/TestPages/

This is the main index file, which is loading

http://flexbeltsite.info/TestPages/_Page3.html

1) The page that contains the contentFlow. As you can see when you go to the index, the contentFlow dosent work.  It only works when you view _Page3.html all by itself. This dosent help me much, as I need it to work on the index page when that page is loaded.

////////////////////////////////////////////////

2) I also would like to make it that when I click on one of the images, It expands (grow animation) to the full width and height of the containing div, the black area.  Then, if you click it again, it shrinks back to its original shape, and goes back in with the rest of the carousel, and the carousel works as normal.

////////////////////////////////////////////////

3) As for the 2nd page, away, id like to make the two sets of tabs and panes work totally independent of each other.  As you can see now if you try to use them, the tabs will control the content of the of the other panes instead of only their own...i dont want that. I need 1 top set of tabs and panes, and 1 bottom set of tabs and panes.  This is what i used to make the tabs and panes if you're curious.

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html

If i can get the cure to these 3 issues, id most greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

***EDIT:***

This is the latest batch of code I am trying, yet i still cannot get it to work. Nothing different is happening. Why? What am i doing wrong?

```
<!--Page Loading Mechanism-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
            e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link


            $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) , function() {
            /* Content is now loaded */
            ThumbnailScroller("tsv_container","vertical",10,800,"easeOutCirc",0.4,500);

    /*Newest Recommended Code from curlackhacker*/
        $.ajax({ url: $( this ).attr( 'href' ), 
        success: function() {
                var contentFlow = new ContentFlow('.ContentFlow');
                contentFlow._init();
       }}); 
        });
      });

   });


</script>
```

Comment: i figured out the tabs issue...Now if someone could help me on my contentflow, id greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

Jules 2nd answer is correct, just call the init method of the contentflow.

```
$.ajax({ url: $( this ).attr( 'href' ), 
        success: function() {
                var contentFlow = new ContentFlow('the id of your content flow');
                contentFlow._init();
       }});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @willingLearner, yes i did. Sorry for coming back to you so late. I see you are passing the class of the content flow. Try passing the id of the content flow and you can instantiate the content flow after the $('#MainWrapper') has loaded.

Comment: @curlackhacker im sorry but i cannot get it to work. Would you be able to whip up a quick working example for me?

Comment: @WillingLearner I will do so. If any one would like to get a copy of the sample, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

1) A few remarks.
When you are loading the page3 as you are doing through  $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) ); you are loading the url's content into the mainwrapper. Which is fine to do, but your page3 is actually an entire HTML page including the     tags.
So what you end up with is your mainpage being similar to (a bit shortened):

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="MainWrapper">
    <html>
        <head>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="ContentFlow/contentflow.js"></script> 
        </head>
        <body>
             Your page3 content...
        </body>
    </html>
</div> 

<div align="center"></div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Which you can see is not proper HTML, having a html and a body tag inside another body tag. So if you are planning on loading the content on the flow using JQuery, I advise you to drop the <html> and <body> tags from the included file (_Page3.html).

2) Then, the reason your contentflow is not working is because that library is autom. initiated using the body load function. So when your homepage HTML has been loaded, that function is being called. But it's only after that that you trigger the JQuery load function to load _Page3.html and its scripts into your main page, so the function inside the contentflow library that is configuring your flow is never being called.

A way to fix this is to make use of the 'success' function of your ajax call. That function is being triggered when your page has finished loading the external page. That means that your _Page3.html has been included into your main page and it's THEN that the contentflow should be configured.

```
$.ajax({ url: $( this ).attr( 'href' ), 
        success: function() {
                //Not sure about this method name, you should look it up in contentflow.js
                onloadInit();
       }});
```

3) Lastly, you can fit the image into your black part of the header by making use of the onclickActiveItem := function(obj item)  method of the contentflow library. And just add your own function there, that does this by selecting the selected image and modifying your header's content, using JQuery, to display the selected image. As described here: http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php

Comment: I understood the first part of your answer....i stripped out the html, body, head, and title tags. Part 2 and 3 im not quite following. Do I replace this code: 
<!--Page Loading Mechanism-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
            e.preventDefault();   
            e.stopPropagation();  
            $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) );  
        });
    }); 
</script>
<!--End Page Loading Mechanism-->
or do i add it to that code? Also,contentflow.js seems encrypted so i cant read it.

Comment: @WillingLearner For #2: You now have: $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) ); which loads the link into the #MainWrapper. After that has been loaded and thus the ContentFlow should be started you have to initiate it. This can be done by adding a Success function:  $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ), function() { var contentFlow = new ContentFlow('the id of ur flow'); contentFlow._init(); } );

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'a.dynamicLoad' ).click( function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();   // prevent the browser from following the link
        e.stopPropagation();  // prevent the browser from following the link


        $( '#MainWrapper' ).load( $( this ).attr( 'href' ) , function() {
           /* Content is now loaded */
           ThumbnailScroller("tsv_container","vertical",10,800,"easeOutCirc",0.4,500);

           //Initiates your contentflow -Jules.
           var contentFlow = new ContentFlow('.ContentFlow');
           contentFlow._init();
        });
  });
```

});

Comment: Im sorry, but id be lying to you if i said i got it working now due to your code. I still remain where I started.

Answer (score 0):

You can add touch support for contentflow in android webview by making the following change in contentflow.js 
replace 
if(this.Browser.iPhone) with 
if(this.Browser.iPhone || this.Browser.WebKit)